# How to have a list having horizontal lines spanning to the end of line in HTML?

Tags: html, horizontal-line

I really have no idea how to create this. Do you have any suggestion?
[image]

Comment: Where is your attempt at it?

Comment: @WaisKamal he said he has no idea xD

Comment: They should read some tutorials on this topic because Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for code.

Comment: @WaisKamal what tutorial I should read? I see there are many questions whose authors saying they don't know where to start, yet still be welcomed. Even googling doesn't yield any result

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try for this

```css
li {
  position: relative
}
li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  z-index: -1
}
li span {
  background-color: #fff
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><span>First line of the list. And for testing length</span></li>
<li><span>Second line of the list</span></li>
<li><span>Third line of the ul. And this is also the last line of the list.Third line of the ul. And this is also the last line of the list</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why do you have to put the items into `span`?

Comment: **span** used here for just to hide the line by adding `background-color: #fff`. Bcoz span is a inline element, which adds background-color to text places only :)